# Targeting a static library to Mac and iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, targets, project-settings

I have a few static library projects which are used in a Mac application, I'm working on porting these libs to the iPhone and I would like to use the project to build both the Mac and iPhone versions.

For that purpose I setup an additional target for the iPhone. This looks like it should work but I see that if I try, for example, to add the UIKit.framework to the project, the framework appears in red.

The problem is, as far as I can see, that in the main project settings "base sdk" is tiger (don't ask). I think I can't change this because I still have a target for mac. Or should I?

So the question is, is it possible to target both mac and iphone from the same project and if so, what should I do with the "Base sdk" setting in the main project setting?

Answer (score 0):

The main project setting doesn't matter. Override the SDK of the target instead.

Comment: I already did that, but the added frameworks appear in red, unless the main project sdk is set.